# Sanitizing Dynamic Form Field Names in jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm dynamically generating a form when a button is clicked. I'm using easily readable strings as labels for some fields which becomes an issue for things like `Size (ft)` since it contains invalid characters suited for form field names. The solution for this particular problem is about 90% from complete and my lack of understanding of regular expressions now becomes an obstacle.

I need a quick method for converting a string from something like `Size (ft)` to something like `Size_ft`. Preservation of case and converting spaces to underscores are all I really want to force. Invalid non-space characters can just be dropped, no need for substitution on those.

**Edit**

Form Variable Gathering:

```
var jFormVars = {};
jFormVars[fieldName] = fieldValue;
```

Form Assembly:

```
jButton.on('click', function() {
  jDiv.find('form').remove(); // Remove existing form...
  var jForm = $('<form action="path/to" method="post" />').appendTo(jDiv);
  $.each(jFormVars, function(key_i, val_i) {
    $('<input name="'+key_i+'" type="hidden" value="'+val_i+'" />').appendTo(jForm);
  });
  jForm.submit(); // Commented for debug .remove();
});
```

**Edit**

Solution as Integrated:

```
var jFormVars = {};
jFormVars[fieldName.replace(/\s+/g, '_').replace(/\W+/g, '')] = fieldValue;
```

Comment: Could you show what you've got so far?

Comment: Updated to include code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Size (ft)` to something like `Size_ft`

You could use something like:

```
var name = "Size (ft)";
name = name.replace(/\s+/g, '_').replace(/\W+/g, '');
```

Comment: Could you explain what I'm looking at in your answer? What does the `/\s+/g` and the `/\W+/g` select?

Comment: Nevermind, I see. So `/\s+/g` does a global whitespace replace into `_` and `/\W+/g` does a global replace into null character. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @MatthewLeeKeith, exactly. The `\W` matches everything which is *not* `[A-Za-z0-9_]` (ASCII letters, numbers or `_`), and it's removed.